# Bokeh figure not updated when mutating the numpy array content in a ColumnDataSource

Tags: python, bokeh

I am wondering if there is a way of letting a figure know that the content of the ColumnDataSource has changed inline. I have a `ColumnDataSource` containing a numpy array, and at figure update I simply want to do some in-place array slice assignments to save allocating memory each time. Something along the lines of `some_renderer.data_has_changed()` to force the update to be visible. The following code shows the issue, where `realloc=True` gives the desired behaviour at the cost of creating a `numpy` array at each update, and `realloc=False` does not update the patch:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select


class AppData:

    def __init__(self, n, realloc=False):
        self.p_source = None
        self.c_source = None
        self.x = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)
        self.n = n
        self.ys = [np.sin(self.x) - i for i in range(self.n)]
        self.realloc = realloc
        self.line = None
        self.patch = None

    def update_module(self, a, b):
        assert b - a == 5

        p_data = dict()
        c_data = dict() 
        if self.p_source is not None: 
            p_data.update(self.p_source.data)
        if self.c_source is not None:
            c_data.update(self.c_source.data)
        ys = [self.ys[j] for j in range(a, b)]
        if "x" not in c_data or self.realloc:
            c_data["x"] = self.x
        if "x" not in p_data or self.realloc:
            p_data["x"] = np.array(c_data["x"].tolist() + c_data["x"][::-1].tolist())

        n_r = len(ys[0])
        n_p = 2*n_r
        if "ys" not in p_data or self.realloc:
            p_data["ys"] = np.empty((n_p))

        p_data["ys"][:n_r] = ys[0]
        p_data["ys"][n_r:] = np.flipud(ys[-1])
        c_data["y"] = ys[2]
        if self.p_source is None:
            self.p_source = ColumnDataSource(data=p_data)
        else:
            self.p_source.data = p_data
        if self.c_source is None:
            self.c_source = ColumnDataSource(data=c_data)
        else:
            self.c_source.data = c_data
        if self.line is not None:
            print(max(self.line.data_source.data["y"]))
            print(max(self.patch.data_source.data["ys"]))  # The value changes, but the figure does not!

# initialize
realloc = False  # Not updating figure - set to True to get the expected behaviour
app_data = AppData(10, realloc=realloc)
app_data.update_module(4, 4 + 5)
s1 = figure(width=500, plot_height=125, title=None, toolbar_location="above")
app_data.line = s1.line("x", "y", source=app_data.c_source)
app_data.patch = s1.patch("x", "ys", source=app_data.p_source, alpha=0.3, line_width=0)
select = Select(title="Case", options=[str(i) for i in range(5)], value="4")

def select_case(attrname, old, new):
    a = int(select.value)
    app_data.update_module(a, a + 5)

select.on_change('value', select_case)
layout = column(select, s1)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = "Example of patches {}being updated".format("not " if not realloc else "")
```

The above code should be runnable with `bokeh serve --show example.py`, given `bokeh` version 0.12.3, and that the script is saved as `example.py`.

The desired plot should move the coloured patch such that the line always stays in the middle of it, but if `realloc` is set to `True`, the patch is not updated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The data  ultimately has to be serialized and sent over the network, then unserialized in the BokehJS client library. There is almost certainly no savings to be had by trying to be clever with slicing, that would outweigh the overhead from those other steps.

The recommended and demonstrated way to cause an update to a data source to cause a plot to update, is to update the `.data` attribute of a data source *all at once*. As one example, from the [sliders demo](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/sliders.py):

```
# Generate the new curve
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
y = a*np.sin(k*x + w) + b

# This causes the plot to change -- nothing else needed
source.data = dict(x=x, y=y)
```

Comment: That is totally true when the consideration is efficiency. The example is really a boiled down version of my code, where my initial idea was to simply bind mutable data to various renderers, and then having the plots updated automatically, or alternatively looping through a list of renderers and tell them all to update. I see now that I have to reconsider my design. Thanks!

Comment: There's not much by "telling things to update" in Bokeh. Setting new property value is generally the thing that does that automatically. The one exception is if you are changing a CDS column *in place*. We can't detect changes like that, so there is an explicit `trigger` that can be called. But that's about the only time that is (possibly) useful. The caveat is that all CDS columns must *always be the same length*, which is why setting all of `.data` at one time is the safest and most recommended technique.

Comment: Possibly of interest to follow, there is an open issue to [support batched updates](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5438)